# Take a parameter from URL, add +1 and insert into an existing script

Tags: javascript

I need to make a very simple change to two existing scripts in order to do the following:

1) take the value of **step=** from the URL (already done, script #1)

2) add +1

3) insert the value in script #2

Example URL
https://www.mywebsite.com?step=1

**Script #1**

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function getURLParameter(name) {  
        var query = window.location.search.substring(1);  
        var vars = query.split("&");  
        for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {  
            var pair = vars[i].split("=");  
            if(pair[0] === name){return pair[1];}  
        }  
        return "";
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
This is step nr. <script>document.write(getURLParameter('step'))</script>!
</body>
</html>
```

**Script #2**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function(){
        bajb_backdetect.OnBack = function(){
            window.history.back=function(){document.location='https://www.mytracker.com/?step='}
        }
    },200);
</script>
```

So basically if the starting URL is this:
https://www.mywebsite.com?step=3

The script #2 will redirect to:
https://www.mytracker.com/?step=4

I'm sure it's very easy, but I've never studied JS and I have no clue!

Comment: is script 2 on the same page as script 1?

Comment: @MattEllen yes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In script 2, you can call the function created in script 1.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout(function(){
  bajb_backdetect.OnBack = function(){
    let step = parseInt(getURLParameter('step')) + 1;
    window.history.back=function(){
      document.location='https://www.mytracker.com/?step='+step;
    }
  }
},200);
</script>
```